# Reasoning about the boolean vector in Coq, based on the value of its sum. (kind of universal instantiation for vectors)

Tags: vector, functional-programming, coq

I've got stuck with theorem which is easy to formulate:

"If the maximal element of the vector is 0 then each element of the vector is 0".

The goal is to be able to use such an idiom as "fold_left orb false v".
So my first aim is to prove this particular lemma:

```
Lemma all_then_some (A:Type) : 
 forall (n:nat) (p:Fin.t (S n))
  (v : Vector.t bool (S n))
  (H : (Vector.fold_left orb false v) = false), 
 (Vector.nth v p) = false.
Proof.
...
```

Some thoughts:

1) To strengthen the hypothesis and prove something like this:

```
(forall (b:bool), (List.fold_left orb l b)  = b) <->
(forall (p:nat), (List.nth p l false) = false)
(** NB: variant for lists here! **)
```

2) Use principle "rectS" from the standard library [/Vectors/Fin.v](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.Fin.html#)

3) Use small scale reflection library.

UPDATE: to find the partial solution please see my answer below.(ged)

UPDATE2: Solution is here: https://github.com/georgydunaev/TRASH/blob/master/UNIV_INST.v
(it is called "Theorem all_then_someV")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a more structured lemma from math-comp, a quick example [that can surely be improved]:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma nat_of_bool_inj : injective nat_of_bool.
Proof. by case=> [] []. Qed.

Lemma all_false n (r : n.-tuple bool) :
  \max_(i in 'I_n) tnth r i <= 0 ->
  forall i, tnth r i = false.
Proof.
by move/bigmax_leqP => H i; apply/nat_of_bool_inj/eqP; rewrite -leqn0 H.
Qed.
```

You have some more specialized lemmas relating `\big[orb/false]` with `has`.

Comment: Thanks for help, +1, but due to complexity of the ssreflect I cannot translate your answer to the desired theorem. I've wrote another answer, which contains a solution with standard library for Lists, and a almost complete solution for Vectors, but with question.

Comment: Well, the code above looks way less complex than anything in the question. What don't you exactly understand? `n.-tuple bool` = vector of size `n`; `'I_n` ordinal less than `n`. The rest should follow. IMO you want to study my answer, and in particular the lemma `bigmax_leqP`.

Comment: Said in a different way, there is something called "big operators"; before tying to reinvent them, I recommend you study the current implementation, theory, and bibliography. Start points: http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/doc/mathcomp-1.5/MathComp.bigop.html https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00331193/document

Answer (score 0):

The code consists of two parts:
I have proved my lemma for List in the 1st part and, similarly, I have almost proved for Vector in the 2nd part.
There is a problem in the last step of the second part.
("induction p." causes "Abstracting over the terms "n0" and "p"  leads to a term … which is ill-typed". I don't understand what shall I do instead of "induction p.".)

```
(*PART 1*)
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint A2 l :fold_left orb l true = true.
Proof.
destruct l; simpl.
reflexivity.
apply A2.
Defined.

Theorem A1 (x y:bool): (orb x y = false)->(x=false)/\(y=false).
Proof. intro H. destruct x, y; firstorder || inversion H. Defined.

Fixpoint A0 b l : fold_left orb (b :: l) false = orb b (fold_left orb l false) .
Proof.
destruct l.
simpl. firstorder.
simpl.
destruct b.
simpl.
apply A2.
simpl.
reflexivity.
Defined.

Fixpoint all_then_some (l:list bool) {struct l}:
(List.fold_left orb l false) = false ->
(forall (p:nat), (List.nth p l false) = false).
Proof.
intros.
destruct l. simpl. destruct p; trivial.
simpl.
rewrite A0 in H.
pose (Q:=A1 _ _ H).
destruct Q.
destruct p. trivial.
apply all_then_some.
trivial.
Defined.
(*PART 2*)
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Import VectorNotations.

Fixpoint B2 (n:nat) (l:t bool n) :fold_left orb true l  = true.
Proof.
destruct l; simpl.
reflexivity.
apply B2.
Defined.

Fixpoint B0 b (n:nat) (l:t bool n) : 
fold_left orb false (b :: l)  = orb b (fold_left orb false l) .
Proof.
destruct l.
simpl. firstorder.
simpl.
destruct b.
simpl.
apply B2.
simpl.
reflexivity.
Defined.

Fixpoint all_then_someV (n:nat) (l:Vector.t bool n) {struct l}:
(Vector.fold_left orb false l ) = false ->
(forall p, (Vector.nth l p  ) = false).
Proof.
intros.
induction l eqn:equa.
inversion p. (* simpl. destruct p; trivial.*)
(*simpl.*)
rewrite B0 in H.
pose (Q:=A1 _ _ H).
destruct Q.
induction p.
```

I think something like the following code can help (because "destruct" tactic is like "_rect" application), but I am not sure.

```
Definition G0 h (n:nat) (l:Vector.t bool n) := fold_left orb false (h :: l) = false.
fold G0 in H.
assert (vari : G0 h n l).
exact H.
clear H.
revert h l vari.
set (P := fun n p => forall (h : bool) (l : t bool n) (_ : G0 h n l),
@eq bool (@nth bool (S n) (cons bool h n l) p) false).
unshelve eapply (@Fin.rectS P).
```

UPDATE2: Solution is here: https://github.com/georgydunaev/TRASH/blob/master/UNIV_INST.v
(it is called "Theorem all_then_someV")